# What are the ways Linux Kernel can communicate with userspace vise versa?

Tags: linux-kernel

How to send a message from Kernel to user space and receive from userspace to the kernel ?

What are possible ways ?. I am a new new guy to kernel module programming.

Adding one more query here related to the same question

How can we send a message from a interrupt(top half) handlerto a user space and response from user space to the same interrupt module ?

Comment: I am reopening this question, because it seems like a completely valid question. A simple list of names so that the OP could go and investigate each of them is a good answer, as ILYA have done.

Comment: Dear Sir, I know that it's very wide, but giving in just 2/3 lines will give a consice idea

Comment: Many thanks  Shahbaz, for validating my query. Can you please try to address my new query ?. TIA

Comment: Which one? They both seem to be answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. IOCTL
2. Netlink sockets
3. /sys and /proc filesystems
4. mmap
5. system calls

Comment: Yes. This is the answer what I want. Thanks @ILYA Khlopotov. Further, updates are always welcome :-)

Comment: If I remember correctly, IOCTL is being deprecated (if not already) and /sys is recommended as a surrogate. /proc was being abused and unless your communication falls in the category of /proc communications, it's recommended to use /sys instead.